How to fix Your database version is incompatible on local dev server?
I think after upgrading my local ubuntu 22.04 I got error running meilisearch :
$ ~/Downloads/meilisearch  --master-key="103c5134-1195-4057-a6bc-0c265580b0f8"
2024-12-25T15:15:51.059452Z ERROR meilisearch: error=Your database version (1.10.2) is incompatible with your current engine version (1.11.3).
To migrate data between Meilisearch versions, please follow our guide on https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/update_and_migration/updating.
Error: Your database version (1.10.2) is incompatible with your current engine version (1.11.3).
To migrate data between Meilisearch versions, please follow our guide on https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/update_and_migration/updating.

I opened guide and  found block :
Updating a self-hosted Meilisearch instance
I read docs :
Step 1: Export data
Verify your database version
First, verify the version of Meilisearch that's compatible with your database using the get version endpoint:

curl \
-X GET 'http://<your-domain-name>/version' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer API_KEY'

I suppose that your-domain-name is localhost:7700 and API_KEY that is master-key is the command I run above
But I got next error :
    curl -X GET 'http://localhost:7700/version'     -H 'Authorization: Bearer 103c5134-1195-4057-a6bc-0c265580b0f8'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7700 after 0 ms: Connection refused


curl \
-X GET 'http://<your-domain-nam>/version' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer 103c5134-1195-4057-a6bc-0c265580b0f8'

Not sure that I use the command correctly.
That is dev local server - so I do not need to import/save  existing data - I will regenerate them.
How to upgrade it ?

Deleting subdirectory
data.ms

inside my project salved the issue
